# unable to refresh the text and screenshots associated with an application published in android marketplace

Tags: android, google-play

After publishing an application - I realized I had to make changes/improvements to the Description and the Screenshots - so I made the changes and saved in the Developer Console. The changes though are not reflected when I view the page from elsewhere. I log back into the Developer Console I can see the changes have been saved. So then I did "unpublish" and then publish - that did not help either.
Please help - is it supposed to work this way? - I think it is reasonable to expect it work this way i.e. make changes/improvement to the description and screenshot of a published application. Please note I am not changing the application's package in any way.
Thank you for taking time ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes time for the changes to ripple through the google servers. I have seen it take several hours for an image to be updated.

Comment: thank you - I was hoping that is the reason - I will continue to wait patiently!